# Psychic Anthropormorphic Cats

Tags: story-identification

I remember a book that is more of a young adult type book. It's about a psychic anthropomorphic cat woman on an alien world. She arrives on this alien world in a classic pulp space opera rocket ship. Most of the weaponry she had I can still imagine in a Buck Rodgers/Barbarella style. The dust cover was blues for the sky and greens for the ground and vegetation. A rocket ship was shown landed.

**Could someone identify this book?**

Comment: Do you remember anything about the plot? What was the character's name? Which of her features were cat-like? Was she from Earth or was she an alien?

Comment: Also, when you say anthroporphic, do you mean like a two-legged humanlike body with a catlike face, or a more feline-looking alien that just behaved in a humanlike way, or something else?

Comment: I seem to remember the protagonist as a bipedal feline. Human or alien, I'm not sure anymore. I also remember the story happening on a jungle planet.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a little bit like "[The Ballad of Lost C'mell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Lost_C'Mell)" by Cordwainer Smith from 1962 (old enough to feature Buck Rogers/Barbarella-esque technology I imagine), where the title character was a genetically created human/cat hybrid named C'mell who worked as a sort of courtesan...I don't think she was telepathic herself but the plot summary says that at one point she was in telepathic contact with another human-animal hybrid. This was a short story rather than a standalone novel, is it possible you read it in a collection like "The Best of Cordwainer Smith", cover below?

[image]

If not, might be worth a try googling the various stories in *[Cats in Space and Other Places](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671721186)* to see if any ring a bell. And if you want to spend some more time searching, I found a large list of stories featuring anthropomorphic cats at http://anthrozine.com/site/lbry/cat.novels.html and some more at http://ask.metafilter.com/231367/Fantasy-novels-featuring-talking-cats-telepathic-cats-sentient-cats-intelligent-cats-etc (this one is focused on fantasy but there are some sci-fi novels in there)

Comment: I do believe it was a stand alone story. Than you though for helping remembering C'mell though. It has been a long time since I had read that story.

Comment: Cordwainer Smith also wrote a novel *Nostrilia* that the publishers edited into two parts, *The Planet Buyer* and *The Underpeople*, the second of which featured C'mell (and in 1975 Ballantine published the full *Nostrilia*). C'mell was apparently the leader of an underground group trying to gain freedom for the humanized animals. Covers don't really look like what you described though, see  http://www.cordwainer-smith.com/underpeople.htm and http://fantasticbookblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/norstrilia/ but could have been some alternate covers I'm not finding on google.

Comment: Another cat-person book with a cover more like what you described is *Firebird* by Charles Harness, which features a male and female cat-person trying to stop an intelligent computer from destroying the universe, cover and quick synopsis at http://www.lwcurrey.com/pages/books/146314/charles-harness/firebird